# How to exit from recovery mode in Ubuntu 18.04, system is stuck after trying to enable networking option?

Tags: 18.04, recovery-mode

After trying to 'enable networking" option in recovery mode in Ubuntu 18.04, the system is stuck. Not able to reboot.

How much time it will take for recovery?

System is stuck in the following screen.

[image]

Please provide your insights. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching TTY. It looks like there is a problem reading the status of the RF Kill switch. Probably it will wait forever for it to come online.

[Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F2] might switch to a new TTY session from which you can reboot by typing:

```
sudo reboot now
```

The reboot might enable the system to read the status of the switch.
Should the key combination not work than a use the power switch to turn the system off (and on again)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The first method was not working. Even hard reboot was not working at that time. I waited for at least 1 hour and later was able to hard reboot using power button.